# How to add data labels in each bar in vertical stacked bar chart in d3.js v4?

Tags: d3.js

I want to add the label text for the each stacked bar chart 
help me in How to add data labels in each bar in vertical stacked bar chart in  d3.js v4?
Here is my code:

```
           /*stacked bar chart start*/
            var margin = {
              top: 40,
              right: 20,
              bottom: 40,
              left: 40
            }

            var width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right
            var height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom

            var data = [{
                    day: 'Mon',
                    apricots: 120,
                    blueberries: 180,
                    cherries: 100
                },
                {
                    day: 'Tue',
                    apricots: 60,
                    blueberries: 185,
                    cherries: 105
                },
                {
                    day: 'Wed',
                    apricots: 100,
                    blueberries: 215,
                    cherries: 110
                },
                {
                    day: 'Thu',
                    apricots: 150,
                    blueberries: 330,
                    cherries: 105
                },
                {
                    day: 'Fri',
                    apricots: 120,
                    blueberries: 240,
                    cherries: 105
                }
            ];

            var svg_stacked = d3.select('#stackedBar')
                .append('svg').classed('stackGraph', true)
                .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append('g').classed('stack_g', true)
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')

            var colors = ['#FBB65B', '#513551', '#de3163'];

            var stack = d3.stack()
                .keys(['apricots', 'blueberries', 'cherries']);

            var stackedSeries = stack(data);

            // Create a g element for each series
            var g = d3.select('.stack_g')
                .selectAll('g')
                .data(stackedSeries)
                .enter()
                .append('g')
                .classed('series', true)
                .style('fill', (d, i) => {
                    return colors[i];
                });

            var stack_x = d3.scaleBand()
                .rangeRound([0, width])
                .padding(0.1)

            var stack_y = d3.scaleLinear()
                .range([height, 0])

            stack_x.domain(data.map((d) => {
                return d.day
            }))

            stack_y.domain([0, d3.max(stackedSeries, function (d) {
                return d3.max(d, function (d) {
                    return d[0] + d[1];
                });
            })])

            svg_stacked.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'x axis')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + height + ')')
                .call(d3.axisBottom(stack_x))

            svg_stacked.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'y axis')
                .call(d3.axisLeft(stack_y))

            // For each series create a rect element for each day
            g.selectAll('rect')
                .data((d) => {
                    return d;
                })
                .enter()
                .append('rect')
                .attr('height', (d) => {
                    return stack_y(d[0]) - stack_y(d[0] + d[1]);
                })

                .attr('y', (d) => {
                    return stack_y(d[0] + d[1]);
                })
                .attr('x', (d, i) => {
                    return stack_x(d.data.day)
                })

                .attr('width', stack_x.bandwidth())
                .style("stroke", "#ccc");
            g.selectAll("text")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .text(function (d) { return d.sightingCount; })
            .attr("x", function (d) { return  stack_x(d.data.day)+  stack_x.bandwidth() / 2; })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return stack_y(d[0] + d[1]) + 12; })
            .style("fill", "white");

        });
```

Comment: Could you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_shimizu/Q5Jag/1/) ? it would be easier to help you.

Comment: thank you hssen.and here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/harishklick/s9bzgc80/2/  and also i need legends for this stacked bar